# unable to read title with yt gem though manual request works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api

I am fairly new to ruby on rails. I am trying to use yt gem to get the details of youtube video. I see the following issue.

"A request to YouTube API caused an unexpected server error: {} You can retry the same request manually by running: curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)"

When i access API URL manually I get the expected details fine.

here are my files and code.

articles_contoller

```
def index
    @article = Article.all
    @campaign = Campaign.all
    @video = Yt::Video.new url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Tzg9173xC4'
    @title = @video.title       
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
```

```
<iframe width="350" height="250"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%=@video.id%>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Response to the API call manually

```html
   
"kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/REiwRaaIO10kgiEe8tHbpNZgd4g\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/wYDY_ffgX0ztxRb89MdmYL7kALY\"",
   "id": "5Tzg9173xC4",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-03-04T09:21:18.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCgZ-2dsrFfrWCskNEwTNFPQ",
    "title": "Anits ECE Flashmob 2k15",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5Tzg9173xC4/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5Tzg9173xC4/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5Tzg9173xC4/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "anits ece",
    "categoryId": "22",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Anits ECE Flashmob 2k15",
     "description": ""
    },
    "defaultAudioLanguage": "en"
   }
  }
 ]
```

I am sure i might be missing something silly. Tried to solve by looking various forums and tutorials but no luck.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Might be a configuration problem. Have you registered your app? https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt#configuring-your-app

Comment: Also, it looks like `Yt::Video.new` accepts an id (which in your case would be `5Tzg9173xC4`)

Comment: @bobby Yes. I registered the App, and I could see the right key populating in the URL populated in error message. I tried with id as well but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue right now - any luck?

---

**Update**

I just fixed the issue - for me it was an error I get in localhost, with SSL.

Add this line to `development.rb` and then try again.

`OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your API key? The best place to do this is in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/youtube.rb

Yt.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = ENV['youtube_key']
end
```