# How can I get the Yt gem to account for defunct channels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api

I've run into a fatal error in using the Yt gem when it tries to get data from this YouTube channel (Beebop Vox):
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxwZWB5WtCntLsjzx8plK6Q

A call to this channel returns an empty array.

This is the error message from the Yt gem:
`A request to YouTube API returned no items but some were expected: {} You can retry the same request manually by running: curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" -H "authorization: Bearer  { USER_TOKEN }" -H "host: www.googleapis.com" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCxwZWB5WtCntLsjzx8plK6Q&maxResults=50&part=statistics"`

This channel is now defunct as it has been transfered to the YOGSCAST network. Presumably this shuffled around its channel id, and my user was still subscribed to the artifact channel. The new Beebop Vox channel is here:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsrgL-QuUioeuAKpbhy69XQ

A call to this channel doesn't return an empty array.

How can I account for this kind of error so that it doesn't crash my application?

Comment: Maybe it was an [SSL issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872808/5832311). Add this line to `development.rb` and then try again: `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`.

Comment: That would open my app up to MTM attacks. I don't think this is an ideal option. This error is occurring in production as well, so I definitely do not want to use that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of posting this question, I didn't know about `raise`. My code was attempting to save data that wasn't there.

Essentially, what I needed to do was

```
begin
  save_youtube_data
rescue
  handle_error
end
```

Even better, I should have handled it further up the chain by doing:

```
if youtube_returns_empty_array
  do_stuff
else
  next
end
```